# Tweenmax ease and ESLINT

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, gsap

I'm using Babel's ES6 transpiller and Tweenmax as my animations library, and it provides some objects that stores easing's curve, such as `Back`, `Sine`, etc.

Thing is that I'm using Eslint aswell, and these easing objects break the no-undef rule (which i don't want to disable).

JS example:

```
import TweenMax from 'gsap';

TweenMax.fromTo('.header__logo', .5, {y: -70, alpha: 0}, {y: 0, alpha: 1, delay: .4, ease: Back.easeOut});
```

Console:

```
   97:98   error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
   98:110  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
   99:109  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  105:85   error  "Sine" is not defined         no-undef
  107:117  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  108:125  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  127:96   error  "Sine" is not defined         no-undef
  133:98   error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  134:151  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  159:103  error  "Sine" is not defined         no-undef
  160:111  error  "Sine" is not defined         no-undef
  165:97   error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  166:109  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
  167:108  error  "Back" is not defined         no-undef
```

## Question

How can I get TweenMax easings to work along with Eslint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i've figured out.

The fastest way is to add GSAP variables to the `globals` property in the .eslintrc file

```
  "globals": {
    "TimelineLite" : false,
    "TimelineMax" : false,
    "TweenLite" : false,
    "TweenMax" : false,
    "Back" : false,
    "Bounce" : false,
    "Circ" : false,
    "Cubic" : false,
    "Ease" : false,
    "EaseLookup" : false,
    "Elastic" : false,
    "Expo" : false,
    "Linear" : false,
    "Power0" : false,
    "Power1" : false,
    "Power2" : false,
    "Power3" : false,
    "Power4" : false,
    "Quad" : false,
    "Quart" : false,
    "Quint" : false,
    "RoughEase" : false,
    "Sine" : false,
    "SlowMo" : false,
    "SteppedEase" : false,
    "Strong" : false,
    "Draggable" : false,
    "SplitText" : false,
    "VelocityTracker" : false, 
    "CSSPlugin" : false,
    "ThrowPropsPlugin" : false, 
    "BezierPlugin" : false
  }
```

*Properties retrieved from [Green Sock forum](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/11369-gsap-globals-for-jshint/)*